# autorun.inf won't open file

Tags: windows, usb, autorun

I want to run the `open` file in `autorun.inf`, but I can not. When I tried to `shellexecute` a `.txt` file, it opened, but in hidden mode. I found `notepad.exe` processes in Task Manager. I can't `shellexecute` `.vbs` file. But I can change the label and icon at my USB. Can anybody help me in this situation?